# 3D cross section of a 4D mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, 4d

First off, I'd like to note that I've seen the [other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775019/how-do-i-get-a-3d-cross-section-of-a-4d-mesh) trying to explain this.

I've read over the topic and tried to implement the math, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm probably doing something wrong.

For reference, I'm using C# in the Unity engine. I'm working on a game simmilar to [Miegakure](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNqSF-tYoFYFxa7aayp_wiA), in the fact that you "turn" to face the fourth dimension, seeing it in slices. This means that projecting 4D objects to 3D doesn't work. I need to get 3D Cross-sections.

I already have this working for my actual terrain itself, since it's voxels which makes it easy to change how the mesh generator iterates through the 4D world.

My current problem is non-voxel meshes. I want to have them in my world, for things like the player, and dynamic blocks that move from dimension to dimension (Therefore giving the effect of hypercubes)

In that post, they use some complicated vector math, which I don't think I understand.

So long story short, I just need a slightly better explanation. Does anyone have a link I can steal of an example from 3D>2D slicing, so I can try and extend it to 4D>3D?

Literally any help, even just a re-explanation of that previous post, or someone translating it to actual script, would be nice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look at this [how should i handle morphing objects in opengl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970550/2521214) may be it will shine some light on the cross section math for you.

Comment: btw why do you think projecting 4D -> 3D -> 2D does not work ? It does (see the 4D teseract with perspective in the link from my previous comment) but the Miegakure style game is specifically designed for cross sections instead of projection as that is "easier" to abstract by human once get into the game.

Comment: @Spektre He is saying that it won't work for his game. It might help if you take a look at the game he's emulating "Miegakure" it's a puzzle game that works by navigating the 4th dimension. He wants a 3D slice not a projection because he wants to intentionally hide the rest of the 4D object for difficulty.

Comment: @JordanLaPrise yep still the linked QA covers both cross section and perspective projection techniques with C++ examples ...  I guess the main probem (s)he got is wrong simplex/primitive ... cubes/voxels are not a good match for  4D instead cross sections it should be 4 point/side tetrahedrons ... which the linked QA deals with too btw ... Anyway (s)he had not respond in almost a year so the Q is dead to me ... at least for now