# Simple implementation of 4D cross-section

Tags: c++, algorithm, 4d

I am trying to calculate the 3D cross-section of a 4D shape. I am having trouble thinking of an algorithm that would do this. The other questions about this haven’t been of much help to me, as I couldn’t understand the answers given. Could someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: What kind of a shape is it ? How do you represent it ?

Comment: see the linked duplicate (I know the title is misleading a lot) the cross sections are handled at the bottom ...

Comment: Look here. Maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775019/how-do-i-get-a-3d-cross-section-of-a-4d-mesh